# Meaning of に in プラスチック**に**は体に悪い物質が付きやすいため

Tags: grammar, particle-に

> プラスチック**に**は体に悪い物質が付きやすいため、魚などがプラスチックを食べると、その魚を食べる動物や人にも悪い影響が出る心配があります。
>   As for plastic, because bad materials easily stick in the body, there is a worry that if fish eat plastic it will also have a bad effect on the people and animals who eat those fish.

I can't understand the purpose of the に in bold at the start of this sentence.

Can it be omitted without changing the meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have failed to parse this sentence correctly. Treat 体に悪い物質 as one set here.

> プラスチック**には**[体に悪い物質]**が**付きやすい…
>   [Substances which are bad for your body] easily stick to plastic, ...

AがBに付く is a common way to say "A sticks to B," and it's not the body but plastic that bad substances stick to. So に after プラスチック is just "to" as in "stick to ～", and に after 体 is "for" as in "bad for ～".

The topicalizer は always replaces が/を, but it doesn't usually replace に/へ. See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/7006/5010).

You can omit に in this case without changing the meaning. But I wouldn't do so because this section is relatively complicated and omitting に may make it a bit harder to understand. See: [When do you use は/に for どようびは/に?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/8269/5010)

Comment: I don't understand why this got down voted.